# EF6 - Get entity for DbUpdateCommandTree in DbCommandTreeInterceptor

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, interceptor

I am trying to get the value of a "NotMapped" property for a Entity/class when intercepting a DbUpdateCommandTree.

I have looked through the various metadata, but I cannot find the "link" to the Entity from the CommandTree, so unfortunately I am stuck.

Is it even possible ?

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int SomeUnmappedProperty { get; set; }
}

public class CommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
        {
            var updateCommand = ctx.OriginalResult as DbUpdateCommandTree;
            if (updateCommand != null)
            {
                // I would like to get a value of a specific property here.
                // Pseudo code
                var val = updateCommand.Entity.GetPropertyValue("SomeUnmappedProperty") as int;
            }
        }
    }
}
```